# How can I add an attribute to serialized object?

Tags: symfony, serialization

I want to add an attribute to every serializer-group of this entity.

Example:

```
class User {
  /**
  * @Groups({"userlist", "profile"})
  */
  protected $username;

  /**
  * @Groups({"profile"})
  */
  protected $name;

  /**
  * This should add to every serialization of this object
  */
  public function getRandomNumber() {
    return rand();
  }
}
```

Output for `userlist`:
`{"username":"nickname", "random_number":54}`

Output for `profile`:
`{"username":"nickname", "name":"Bob", "random_number":54}`

Output for `special`:
`{"random_number":54}`

Important is, that I don't know all serializer-groups for this entity.

Comment: unserialize, add attribute, reserialize?

Answer (score 1):

Just add annotation `@Groups({"userlist", "profile"})` to your method, like this

```
   /**
    * @Groups({"userlist", "profile"})
    */
   public function getRandomNumber() 
   {
       return rand();
   }
```

or you can create your [custom normalizer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer/custom_normalizer.html) only for `User` entity

Comment: A custom normalizer for all entities would be the right solution.